# Netbeans - running external scripts from IDE

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

I'm using NB 7.1 for PHP in my daily routine. Many of my projects have some shell/command line scripts that I have to run quite often (i.e. behat tests).

Is there a way to create such list of scripts in ide to run automatically? I've read about plugin external tools but its unavailable for 7.1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing C/C++ plugin, and you can run sh scripts from context menu on file in project. Put your command in sh file, put sh file to bin directory. Also you can add them to favorites to separate panel.

It still working with 7.3.